# Unable to retrieve posts from API in Android app

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I'm currently working on an Android social media application, and I'm facing an issue with retrieving posts from the API. I'm using Retrofit to make the API call, and although the call is successful, I'm not receiving any posts in the response.

Here's the relevant information:

> API endpoint: https://api.example.com/api/v1/post/post
> Request method: GET
> Required parameters: page (int), size (int)
> Request header: Authorization (contains a valid authentication token)

I have verified that the API call is being made correctly, and the authentication token is included in the request header. However, the response I receive does not contain any posts.

Here are the relevant logs in Android Studio:

```
2023-07-07 16:21:23.737  I  Auth Token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJqb2huQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInJvbGVzIjpbIlVTRVIiXSwiaXNzIjoiL2FwaS92MS9sb2dpbiIsImV4cCI6MTY4ODc0MzI4Mn0.LaYnVqLrUtAG7weC0hk56W7anVt9nWmYet8Zg1lAuOg
2023-07-07 16:21:32.075  I  we should get the posts here retrofit2.OkHttpCall$NoContentResponseBody@df0ef6d
2023-07-07 16:21:32.076  I  number of posts: 0
2023-07-07 16:21:32.076  I  total pages: 0
2023-07-07 16:21:32.076  I  total elements: 3
```

As you can see, the response indicates that there are no posts (number of posts: 0) even though there are actually 3 posts available.

What I return in Postman:

[image]

Here's the relevant code snippet for making the API call:

```
// Make the API call to fetch the list of posts
PostService postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);
Call<PostPage> call = postService.getAllPosts(authToken,10, 15); // Replace page and size with your desired values
call.enqueue(new Callback<PostPage>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<PostPage> call, Response<PostPage> response) {
        System.out.println("we should get the postts here " + response.raw().body().toString());
        System.out.println("header check "  + response.headers());
        if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body()!=null) {
            PostPage postResponse = response.body();
            List<Post> posts = postResponse.getPosts();
            if (posts != null) {
                int totalPages = postResponse.getTotalPages();
                long totalElements = postResponse.getTotalElements();
                System.out.println("number of posts: " + posts.size());
                System.out.println("total pages: " + totalPages);
                System.out.println("total elements: " + totalElements);
                postAdapter.setPostList(posts);
            } else {
                // Handle the case when the 'posts' list is null
                System.out.println("Received null posts list");
            }
        } else {
            // Handle error
            // Handle the login error here
            System.out.println("Something went wrong displaying the post");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

And here's the relevant code snippet from the server-side controller:

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/post/post")
public ResponseEntity<PostPage> getAllPost(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
                                           @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size,
                                           @RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorizationHeader) {
    // Extract email from the authorization header and retrieve the user
    // ...

    // Retrieve the posts using the page and size parameters
    Page<Post> post = postService.getAllPost(PageRequest.of(page, size));
    List<Post> posts = post.get().toList();

    // Create a PostPage object and set the necessary fields
    PostPage postPage = new PostPage();
    postPage.setPosts(posts);
    postPage.setTotalPages(post.getTotalPages());
    postPage.setTotalElements(post.getTotalElements());
    postPage.setCurrentPage(post.getNumber());

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(postPage);
}
```

I have already checked the API endpoint, request parameters, and server-side code, and they seem to be correct. However, I'm unable to retrieve the posts in my Android app. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

After almost 3 days of debugging and hours of scrapping the internet for solutions, I discovered that the issue was with the usage of the page and size parameters in the API call. Initially, I mistakenly used the @Query annotation instead of manually fixing the server-side controller to be able to handle paging and size as part of the query.

which made a get request to the server with this path http://localhost:8080/api/v1/post/post?page=10&size=10

when I was expecting to make a get request to this path
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/post/post

Consequently, the API call did not return any posts, even though it appeared to be successful. That's what confused me.